# After installation of Hyperon not able to browse http://localhost:38080/hyperon/app

Tags: hyperon

I have installed Hyperon a business rule engine on windows machine.
I have fallowed instruction to install it from:
- https://www.hyperon.io/tutorial/installing-hyperon-studio
After installation I have browse below URL to see whether #Hyperon web app is running or not.

http://localhost:38080/hyperon/app

I am getting this error:

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ICeL.png)

Reproduceable Steps:

1. Downloaded hyperon zip and extracted it.
2. Open the file directory and reach to the /bin folder
3. Opened it in command prompt:
4. Ran startup.bat file.

Refer to below screenshot:
[command prompt logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jx3ZW.png)
[tomcat command prompt logs and output after executing- startup.bat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vu1O.png)

Comment: Could you please attach log file (or some part of it)? It is located in file $HYPERON_DIR/logs/hyperon.log. Are you using embedded (default) or an external DB?

Comment: Hi @przemekhertel, 
hyperon.log file is not generated.

Reproduceable Steps:

1. Downloaded hyperon zip and extracted it.
2. Open the file directory and reach to the /bin folder 
3. Opened it in command prompt:
4. Ran startup.bat file.

Refer to above latest screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Such effect occurs when trying to run hyperon with JDK 8.
Hyperon Studio requires JDK 11.

See installation guide:
https://www.hyperon.io/tutorial/installing-hyperon-studio

If you have multiple JDKs installed, you can swith to proper by setting JAVA_HOME variable:

for example:

```
cd c:\hyperon-studio-2.1.9\bin
set JAVA_HOME=c:\java\jdk-11.0.4
startup.bat
```

The first run may take a minute, because hyperon needs to initialize database schema.
Once it is fully started you will see hyperon.log file and should be able to access localhost:38080/hyperon/app.